# Когда _stdcall, а когда cdecl?

Tags: c, c++

Зачем и когда употреблять нужно их? Можно на примере кода C/C++ (не asm)?

Comment: в основном тогда, когда работаете с dll. Эти директивы уточняют, как передавать параметры функции (через стек, через регистры, кто чистит стек по завершению).

Comment: В WinAPI, как правило, применяется stdcall, кроме случаев, когда функция должна принимать произвольное количество параметров (например, wsprintf).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[@xinakapu](/users/22460/xinakapu), Вы уже прочли в статью в вики?

Боюсь, что вот это:

```
avp@avp-xub11:hashcode$ cd /usr/include
avp@avp-xub11:include$ grep -i stdcall *.h */*.h
i386-linux-gnu/zconf.h:     /* For complete Windows  compatibility, use WINAPI, not __stdcall. */
avp@avp-xub11:include$ grep -i cdecl *.h */*.h
i386-linux-gnu/zconf.h:#      define ZEXPORTVA FAR CDECL
avp@avp-xub11:include$
```

и есть ответ на Ваш вопрос.

Впрочем, подозреваю, что в Windows мы бы увидели другую картину.